# Select2 add placeholder after creation

Tags: yii, jquery-select2

I have an existing Select2 dropdown that is generated by my framework (Yii). Unfortunately there's no way to specify a placeholder. Is there any way to add it afterwards?

The dropdown is generated as follow:
`$form->inputRow(TbInput::TYPE_SELECT2, $model, 'id_tecnico', null,
array('data' => $utenti,'class' => 'span12 adaptContainerCssClass',));`

[image: App with Select2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a programmatic way to do it with select2 options, but you can modify the text with jQuery after select2 has initialized:

`$('.select2-chosen').text("New Placeholder Text");`

The `.select2-chosen` element is the span that wraps the placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

There's how to add a default value for a `dropDownList` on `Yii Framework`.

```
echo $form->dropdownList($model,'variable', $data, array('prompt'=>'Choose One')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'pluginOptions' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Your place holder',
            'width' => '40%',
            'tokenSeparators' => array(',', ' '),
        )
```

but if you want to retain the key value pairs just do it this way

```
$form->inputRow(TbInput::TYPE_SELECT2, $model, 'id_tecnico', null,
array('data' => array(-1=>"Your first Element")+$utenti,'class' => 'span12 adaptContainerCssClass',));
```

The + operator will add the array to your key value pair without changing the key values.